# How to move files in trash to specific folder

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-folder

I've a large amount of files and folders in trash and I now can't be sure if I want to permanently delete them.

I'd like to move all of the contents of trash into a specific folder for checking later.

But the drag-drop functionality doesn't seem to work to move the files and folders.

This may have happened due to my Google Client, InSync (actually correctly) moving files to trash as I re-organised. The trouble is because this was done over some time, I've now forgotten the rationality of why the files are in trash.

So how can I do this?

**Workaround**

I do have a workaround, but would prefer something simpler - like the actual ability to move the files and folders as I've said.

My work around is:

1. Backup my Google Drive - make a copy of the entire folder structure
   and files, from the drive synced to a local machine folder
2. Restore all the files from the trash
3. Use Beyond Compare to compare my backup copy with the current
   contents of Google Drive (in the local machine synced folder) to see where the files and folders got
   added back.
4. Review these files and folders as required.
5. Possibly also use MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder (FDFF) to purge any
   duplicates against the existing drive folder contents (synced to the local machine folder) and structure,
   with the option enabled in this software to only flag duplicates in the
   backup copy not the current drive itself (so as to ensure the correct duplicate gets removed and that no further deletions entries appear in the trash).

This will definitely get me the result I need but I'd like something less involved, like Google Drive not have irritatingly removed the drag drop functionality for the trash this is bad UX (User Experience).

I also have MountainDuck google client and if there is a trash can that this provided through it's mounted drive letter folder, as direct mirror to google drive trash, then I could use that perhaps but I don't know if it does.

(No affiliation with any of the software tools mentioned).

Comment: What do you mean by "But the drag-drop functionality doesn't seem to work to move the files and folders."? What web browsers are you using? Have you already tried using your web browser in private/incognito/safe mode?

Comment: +1 thank you for your time replying @Rubén I'm using Chrome. Have you tried it yourself with the Google Drive web client Trash folder - tried to drag files from there to other folders?